# using minimum_match inside filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a elastic-call where I wanna sett some filters within a curtain area, what I would like to do is something like:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query"  : {
                "match_all" : { }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "and" : [
                    {
                        "bool" : {
                            "must" : {
                                "terms" : {
                                    "my_filter"     : [1, 2, 4],
                                    "minimum_match" : 3
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "geo_distance" : {
                            "location" : "56.20123,14.3240234",
                            "distance" : "30km"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

however when trying this all I get is "minimum_match is not allowed for terms in filter, is there any way around this?

I've tried to use the bool as the query but I was not allowed to filter on that one

Comment: Could you post the condition.. Lemme post the query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please make a try `minimum_match` with query. as below

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "and": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                     "query": {
                        "terms": {
                                "my_filter"     : [1, 2, 4],
                                "minimum_match" : 3
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "geo_distance": {
                        "location": "56.20123,14.3240234",
                        "distance": "30km"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```